# ListAdapter for loading json file in a fragment

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, fragment, listadapter

I'm using a adapter class for controlling a ListView in my Fragment. My Adapter class extends SimpleAdapter and it works fine when I use in for an activity. But it fails in a fragment.

Here is the code of my **adapter**:

```
class TrackAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
Context context;
public TrackAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    this.context = context;
}





@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final TrackAdapter proxy = this;
    final View trackView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    final TextView name = (TextView) trackView.findViewById(R.id.name)

        }
    });
    return trackView;
}
```

and here in the code of Fragment:

```
public class Poems extends android.app.Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies, container, false);

    ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);

    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray m_jArry = null;
        try {
            m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("poems");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> formList= new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> m_li;

            for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.d("Details-->", jo_inside.getString("name"));
                String names = jo_inside.getString("name");


                //Add your values in your `ArrayList` as below:

                m_li=new HashMap<String, String>();
                m_li.put("name", names );


                formList.add(m_li);
                //Same way for other value...

            }
            /*
            adapter = new Adapter(Names.this , formList);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("araaaay"  , formList.toString() );*/
            ListAdapter adapter1 = new TrackAdapter(
                    Poems.this, formList,
                    R.layout.list_view, new String[] { "name"}, new int[] { R.id.name});

            listview.setAdapter(adapter1);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    return rootView;
}

//--------------------------------------------
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("myjson.json");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;

}
```

The error is for this part:

```
ListAdapter adapter1 = new TrackAdapter(
                    Poems.this, formList,
                    R.layout.list_view, new String[] { "name"}, new int[] { R.id.name});
```

Is there anyway to change the constructor of TrackAdapter to fix the error?? If not, Is there any other sample adapter for my problem???

Comment: change Poems.this to this.getActivity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
ListAdapter adapter1 = new TrackAdapter(
                Poems.this, formList,
                R.layout.list_view, new String[] { "name"}, new int[] { R.id.name});
```

to this:

```
 ListAdapter adapter1 = new TrackAdapter(
                getActivity(), formList,
                R.layout.list_view, new String[] { "name"}, new int[] { R.id.name});
```

Comment: Thanks it is fixed now!